# Why do Laravel and CodeIgniter have their own [query-builder] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Why do [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) and [CodeIgniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter) have their own query-builder tags?

[laravel-query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-query-builder) [codeigniter-query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter-query-builder)

Whilst you can be an expert in specifically Laravel's or CodeIgniter's query builder, you would presumably also be an expert of the framework itself, so wouldn't using [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) or [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) in addition to a plain old [query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-builder) be better?

So why don't we merge [laravel-query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-query-builder) and [codeigniter-query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter-query-builder) into [query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-builder)?

Comment: Alternatively, let's get rid of the ambiguous "query-builder" tag, since it doesn't mean anything in particular, and is hard to be an expert in an abstract concept. That tag is a mess.

Comment: Are those Laravel and CodeIgniter query builders specific to Laravel and CodeIgniter, respectively, or are they general tools?